# Python: How to run two loops simultaneously and pass iterative arguments to them?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to run two loops using multi-threading. The iteration for both the loops should give a combined sum of 100.
For Example:

```
def loopA():
   for i in xrange(1,100):
       Do A

def loopB():
   for j in xrange(1,100):
       Do B
```

Now the sum i+j at any given time should be 100

```
    threadA = Thread(target = loopA)
    threadB = Thread(target = loobB)      
    threadA.run()
    threadB.run()
```

So when loop A runs once, loop B should run 99 times simultaneously.(i+j=100)
loop A runs twice, loop B should run 98 times simultaneously.

This should continue till loop A runs 99 times and loop B runs only once.

Comment: Multithreading is not synchronous. If you want them to match in a certain way at all times, you should probably do it in one thread. Either way, I suspect you're dealing with an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - Not exactly. I want to encrypt and decrypt two strings simultaneously. The total number of encryption rounds + Total number of decryption rounds should be equal to 100. This was the only possible solution came to my mind. Plz suggest if you have any other way?!

Comment: @user3743246 Sounds like an XY problem to me! :) You need to do this in the same thread. Once you've started the separate threads, you no longer have concurrency control.

Comment: "the sum of counter 1 + counter 2 at any given moment should be 100". Isn't that what it's doing now? What's the problem?

Comment: Also this might be a good time to remind you that because of the global interpreter lock, multi-threading does not speed up any activity in (C)Python.

Comment: @Kevin no, I think he means `loopA.i + loopB.j == 100`

Comment: @Kevin i rephrased the question to remove the confusion.

Comment: @AdamSmith yes thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: Ok, but if `loopA` runs five times, and `loopB` runs 95 times, how can `i` and `j` always sum up to 100? When `j` equals `50`, `i` can't equal 50, because it only goes from 0 to 5.

Comment: I might be wrong with the multi-threading approach then. but simply put..
when i=1 j should be 99.. when i=2, j should be equal to 98. And both these loops run simultaneously

Comment: so when code inside first loop runs once, the code inside second loop runs 99 times simultaneously

Comment: Python won't run all of a loop's iterations at once. I think it's more likely that what you need is a nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take threading out of the picture to begin with, because it sounds like even *you* aren't sure exactly what you're trying to do. Let's also stop naming them confusingly, and instead call a rose a rose.

```
def encrypt(s, n):
    """Runs string s through n rounds of encryption"""
    for _ in range(n):
        s = some_encryption_method(s)
    return s

def decrypt(s, n):
    """Runs string s through n rounds of decryption"""
    for _ in range(n):
        s = some_decryption_method(s)
    return s
```

From here it's pretty clear how to proceed.

```
for encrypt_rounds in range(101):  # 0 -> 100 inclusive
    decrypt_rounds = 100 - encrypt_rounds
    encrypted_s = encrypt(some_string, encrypt_rounds)
    decrypted_s = decrypt(some_string, decrypt_rounds)
```

Why do you want to do this in a thread? It's not clear what you're gaining from using threading, but it ***is very*** clear that losing synchronicity is a problem. Let's keep it simple, then, and drop threading altogether until we know we need it!